# Is it possible to create a dynamic multi-dimensional ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Here is part of my code:

```java
// regex = [;,.:<>(){}|\s]
// locList is the line of source code
public static multi_dimension_arraylist parser(String regex, List<String> locList) {
    Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile(regex);
    for (String ln : locList) {
        for (String word : ptn.split(ln)) {   // split to words[] and passto word
            // check the word content whether is a function name
            // if so, multi_dimension_arraylist[x][0] = word; //(the function name)
            // then, all of the words in the function store in multi_dimension_arraylist[x][1...n]
            // then continue to the next function, and so on.
        }
    }
    return multi_dimension_arraylist;
}
```

`multi_dimension_arraylist` is an ArrayList
`multi_dimension_arraylist[0 ... x][0 ... y]`

maybe some dimension will be like:

```
multi_dimension_arraylist[0][0 ~ 7]
multi_dimension_arraylist[1][0 ~ 3]
multi_dimension_arraylist[2][0 ~ 9]
...
multi_dimension_arraylist[m][0 ~ n]
```

and I want to make it to become like below:

```
multi_dimension_arraylist form
  [
   [[function_name_1], [function_name_1], ...],
   [[function_name_2], [function_name_2], ...],
   ...
  ]
```

Words in `[function_name_1]`'s and the words in `[function_name_2]`'s might be different.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -  sorry about my poor describe

Comment: My current solution is, "Create another arraylist (called `topLevelList` for example) to store parsed arraylist (for those content in each function)".

Comment: eg. `parsed_list_n = function_1_contents, function_2_contents, function_3_contents, ...`.



Then, `topLevelList [ parsed_list_1, parsed_list_2, parsed_list_3, ... ]`